# Send Email & Create Order programmatically on Product page with Custom form

Tags: email, magento, magento2

When customer enters the details in the form fields and enter submit button then the **Order email should send customer's email immediately and also Order should be created in Backend as well**. Once its submitted(After email sent & order created), the success message will display on same current product page.

For this, I haved added my Custom order form on my theme's product detailed page. Form contains the fields like Name, Email, Quantity, Product Name and Price(Current Product Name & Price when customer Visits).

How to send email and create order programmatically on Product page custom form?

Any help mostly appreciated.

Comment: will your form include payment option also or it will be set cod or something offline  ?

Comment: yes, its COD payment option

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a block class for your template ( there are many resources on how to create a controller for Magento 2, you can reference them).

There you can have a method that gets the product URL for adding the order:

```
public function getAddProductUrl($product, $additional = [])
{
    return $this->_cartHelper->getAddUrl($product, $additional);
}
```

Then in your phtml template file add the following html form and javascript or somethng similar to this:

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
    "[data-role=tocart-form]": {
    "catalogAddToCart": {}
    }
    }
</script>
<div class="product-add-form">
    <?php $product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
    <form data-product-sku="<?= /* @NoEscape */ $product->getSku() ?>"
          action="<?= /* @NoEscape */ $block->getAddProductUrl($product) ?>" method="post" data-role="tocart-form">
        <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $product->getId() ?>" />
        <?= $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
        <button type="submit" title="<?php echo /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Cart'); ?>" class="action primary tocart">
            <span><?php echo /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Add to Cart'); ?></span>
        </button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Please read my question, need to create order when user submit my custom form on product detailed page.